# NoClassDefFoundError when running an OSGI bundle as classic jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management, tycho

I have common code between a Java application and an RCP application. So I have created an OSGI bundle which contains:

- a main class to use it as a classic jar
- an OSGi manifest to use it in my RCP application

I built all with Tycho Manifest-first and it worked fine until I needed to use an external jar in my common code.

I need to use jsch so I have add jsch in my MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Main-Class: mygroupid.Main
Bundle-Name: Common tools
Bundle-SymbolicName: common-tools
Bundle-Version: 1.0.1.qualifier
Export-Package: mygroupid,
      mygroupid.tools
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Require-Bundle: com.jcraft.jsch;bundle-version="0.1.46"
```

I build my RCP application with Tycho and it works. But when I run the bundle as pure JAR with `java -jar myjar.jar`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
```

If I export my bundle with Eclipse, it works. So I have an error in my tycho configuration...

How to solve this problem ?
Is there a jar-with-dependencies for Tycho ? It seems not to be the case
What I have missed ?

(My configuration: Eclipse Juno with m2e, Tycho 0.16.0, p2: Juno, Tycho: packaging>eclipse-plugin, target-platform-configuration : resolver=p2 and pomDependencies=consider.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) to your build, and let it build a jar with all dependencies:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Alternatively, you can also create an assembly where the jars are [packed individually](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html). You'll need to write your own [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on Linux/Unix platform, you can try
java -classpath :myjar.jar com.yourpackage.mainclass

if you are workin on windows platform, you can try
java -classpath ;myjar.jar com.yourpackage.mainclass

Comment: Yes, I know classpath. But I need a complete OSGI bundle as Eclipse can do it. I want to deploy only one jar for the command line version. How to build it with Tycho ?

Comment: You can try to compare the MANIFEST.MF you wrote with eclipse export generated.